# Getting error while runnig neo4j-mazerunner project

Tags: docker, neo4j, neo4j-mazerunner

I'm trying to run the project neo4j-mazerunner of Kenny Bastani but it gives me an error :

```
root@salma-SATELLITE-C855-1EQ:~/workspace/neo4j-mazrunner# docker run 1cddd1005556
Starting message broker: rabbitmq-server.


    __  ______ _____   __________  __  ___   ___   ____________  
   /  |/  /   /__  /  / ____/ __ \/ / / / | / / | / / ____/ __ \ 
  / /|_/ / /| | / /  / __/ / /_/ / / / /  |/ /  |/ / __/ / /_/ / 
 / /  / / ___ |/ /__/ /___/ _, _/ /_/ / /|  / /|  / /___/ _, _/  
/_/  /_/_/  |_/____/_____/_/ |_|\____/_/ |_/_/ |_/_____/_/ |_|   

=========================
Mazerunner is running...
=========================
To start a PageRank job, access the Mazerunner PageRank endpoint
Example: curl http://localhost:7474/service/mazerunner/analysis/pagerank/KNOWS
Error: Could not find or load main class org.mazerunner.core.messaging.Worker
```

can anyone help me with this